# Trying to put an image in html

Tags: html, node.js

Easy question - very tired to find the answer.

I am doing the following :

```
a(href="https://github.com/xxx")
            img#github-banner(style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0;border:0;", src="app\public\img\logo_github.png", alt="View our project on GitHub")
```

The image src here is changed between both project path and full path, but all I get is broken  image and alternate text in that order. Whats the error?

Also any good way to debug these issues ?

Comment: Check in the HTML output the path produce by your code

Comment: I'm sorry, the page or resource you are searching for is currently unavailable. - This is what it leads to in the html output. This image exists in the location I just mentioned though.

Comment: You should use forward slashes. There is hardly a reason to ever use backward slashes.

Comment: And if you try with another image? Or the format? Pay attention that some servers are case-sensitives (difference between "png" and "PNG" for example)

Comment: Tried forward slashes, tried different images, png/PNG - I'm sorry, the page or resource you are searching for is currently unavailable. - This is what it leads to in the html output.

Comment: Judging by the image path, I'd assume that you don't need "app/public" and could just use "img/logo_github.png"

Comment: @RobertMesserle - That did it. How did you judge by the path ? the file I wrote this code was under app\server\views\layout.jade

Comment: With most servers that I've worked with, the public directory is exposed at the root level.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably not with your code, but with the path to your image.

I assume you're using Express, and I'm guessing your `app/public` folder is pointed to by an `express.static()` middleware. This is the default in most cases.

If that's all true, then the path to your image should just be `/img/logo_github.png`.  Try navigating to that in your browser first (with your app running, of course) and see what you get.

Comment: I fixed it with one of the comments but thank you for the reasoning. Now I know why!